# Facebook App Creation With New Account

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-apps

I have been trying to create a Facebook application with a new Facebook personal account. For whatever reason, my account keeps getting blocked when I try to set up the App Name and Namespace.  Facebook says that they have detected that my account is fake, even though its not.

I get the error that they think my account may not be authentic.

The issue is that I do have a real account, and have even verified it with my mobile phone, however I still get this error. Granted, since the account is new, there are no wall posts, friends, pictures, or even a college affiliation.  However the name in the account is real, along with he email account.

Can anyone tell me what the minimum criteria is for Facebook to approve your account as a real one, and not a fake one?  I am not talking about the general Facebook stuff about their rules and regulations, but how active do you need to be on Facebook to create an app?  Is there a certain period of time that they wait to verify that you are a "real person"?  Do they want you to always verify your payment information in order to create an app?  Any insights would help.

Thanks

Comment: I also experienced the same problem now its solved. Thanks for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is pretty tight-lipped about how they regulate their security.  It's to slow up people from trying to get around it.  Basically you have to take their error messages and documentation for what it's worth.  They provide the API free of charge which invites all sort of folk to attempt to exploit it.

That said, I'd be sure to email verify the account as well as put up a profile image.

Comment: Yeah, I put up a profile image, and even verified my mobile phone, but still no dice. I found a way around this for now, however I'll definitely have to figure this out in the future. Don't want to be developing several different apps for my clients under my personal profile.

Comment: Then you have a fake profile and Facebook reserves the right to revoke you apps at any time, which then affects your customers.  :( :( :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to have my customers set up personal accounts, and then i'll develop for them there.  It's just cleaner that way than using my own account.  That's what I did to solve this issue.  
Originally, we wanted to set it up to go under a separate business account but then found out that it wouldn't work.

The problem with using personal accounts is that if someone's personal account gets compromised, then all the apps that they "own" can potentially be compromised as well, and thus compromise the people who use that app as well.

Comment: yeah, it's a slippery slope the way Facebook has it setup.  What if the developer for the company, leaves the company without granting another developer Admin?  It's happened with my own company. Potentially it might not be a fun process to get a former employee to hand over the reigns... But I like your solution.  Make the client create the app and grant you developer permissions on the app  :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook security is strict, If you are creating new account in Facebook for apps, than first you have to verify it with your mobile number. Some time after giving mobile number Facebook does not verify your Application name and Namespace.
I think for creating new apps, your account should be verify as well as Facebook profile should be filled properly.Facebook does not take any charges for creating new apps. Its free!.